# how to auto pull data from a Table(s) that is named different daily

Tags: sql

Hello I am trying to update a MASTER TABLE with a new table daily,
the table name is different daily example [Collections_LT5_PH7_20160117],[Collections_LT5_PH7_20160118]...etc.
 so far this is my update query.

```
INSERT INTO [Collections_LT5_PH7_Master]
(
Date_ID, 
Record_Num,
SITE_ID,
ACCT_NUM,
PHONE_NUM,
Dial_Count,
Call1_Phone,
Call1_dt,
Disp1_Id,
Call2_Phone,
Call2_dt,
Disp2_Id,
Phone1TimeZoneId
)
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()), 112) as Data_ID,
Record_Num,
SITE_ID,
ACCT_NUM,
PHONE_NUM,
Dial_Count,
Call1_Phone,
Call1_dt,
Disp1_Id,
Call2_Phone,
Call2_dt,
Disp2_Id,
Phone1TimeZoneId,

FROM [Collections_LT5_PH7_20160118]
```

I would like to update without having to manually change the date in the table the data is getting pulled from, for the day before. I have tried

```
FROM '[Collections_LT5_PH7_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()), 112)+']'
```

but it errors out.

any ideas?

Comment: Why create new tables for each day... have the date as a column and use indexes... that is what they are for... to optimize queries.  If you ever wanted to get an aggregation of date ranges, you have to join every table by date.

Comment: the tables are loaded in .txt format via a web portal and the system translates them into a Table in the database. The system we use is purchased and is coded to work that way, We are combining the tables into a master table just now to query easier for data when we are unsure of the dates the data falls into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were almost there

try this once happy with the query uncomment the execute part:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO [Collections_LT5_PH7_Master]
(
Date_ID, 
Record_Num,
SITE_ID,
ACCT_NUM,
PHONE_NUM,
Dial_Count,
Call1_Phone,
Call1_dt,
Disp1_Id,
Call2_Phone,
Call2_dt,
Disp2_Id,
Phone1TimeZoneId
)
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()), 112) as Data_ID,
Record_Num,
SITE_ID,
ACCT_NUM,
PHONE_NUM,
Dial_Count,
Call1_Phone,
Call1_dt,
Disp1_Id,
Call2_Phone,
Call2_dt,
Disp2_Id,
Phone1TimeZoneId

FROM [Collections_LT5_PH7_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()), 112)+']'

PRINT (@SQL)
--EXECUTE (@SQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically set table names into an SQL query, I'm guessing this is a security feature.

You can sort of get around it by using a prepared statement and the 'EXECUTE' command.  The following works in MySQL, obviously you would need to modify the query string and the table name being filled to the one you want.

```
set @tablename := 'test';
set @q := 'select * from ';
select concat(@q,@tablename) into @s;
prepare stmt from @s;
execute stmt;
```